# noweave not respecting indentation

Tags: indentation, python, literate-programming

In the past, I have often used noweb for Python projects, but this time I get strange behavior: indentation is not respected in the weaved file. Here is a minimal example, using noweb 2 (version `noweave.nw,v 1.6 1998/08/17 00:10:34`):

```
Test file. Here is some Python code:

<<main>>=
for i in range(100):
    i += 1
    <<printing>>

@
And some more code:
<<printing>>=
repr(i)
```

When I notangle it I get the correct Python code:

```
for i in range(100):
    i += 1
    repr(i)
```

When I weave it, I get the following TeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{noweb}\pagestyle{noweb}\noweboptions{}\begin{document}\nwfilename{test.nw}\nwbegindocs{0}Test file. Here is some Python code:% ===> this file was generated automatically by noweave --- better not edit it

\nwenddocs{}\nwbegincode{1}\moddef{main}\endmoddef\nwstartdeflinemarkup\nwenddeflinemarkup
for i in range(100):
    i += 1
    \LA{}printing\RA{}

\nwendcode{}\nwbegindocs{2}\nwdocspar
And some more code:
\nwenddocs{}\nwbegincode{3}\moddef{printing}\endmoddef\nwstartdeflinemarkup\nwenddeflinemarkup
repr(i)

\nwendcode{}\end{document}
```

which looks OK (at least it is not different from what I was getting in the last 20 years or so), but when compiled it produces the following output:

[image]

where indentation between `for i in range(100):` and the two following lines has disappeared. In Python, indentation is very important since it denotes code block nesting.

Does anyone know how to circumvent this problem and return to the earlier behavior of noweave, which was respecting indentation (whether I used tabs or strings of 4 spaces)?

Comment: Just a guess, itcan be the font. Try change it in the .sty file. There were changes over the years and noweb was using LaTeX 2.09!  I would also try and use docstrip/doc system rather than noweb, but then it might not be as fun!

Comment: I used it both with Computer Modern and pdftex engine (as I did for the last 20 years) and FreeSerif and xetex engine—in both cases, I get the same result. My guess is that something in TeXLive 2022 LaTeX has prevented the noweave-generated TeX code to represent spaces as such (as is done in verbatim mode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something changed in the managing of verbatim mode.

In order to get back the original expected behavior you can add somewhere (possibly at the end of `noweb.sty`)

```
\let\obeyedspace\@xobeysp
```

Proof of concept:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{noweb}
\pagestyle{noweb}
\noweboptions{}

\makeatletter
\let\obeyedspace\@xobeysp
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nwfilename{test.nw}\nwbegindocs{0}

Test file. Here is some Python code:% ===> this file was generated automatically by noweave --- better not edit it

\nwenddocs{}\nwbegincode{1}\moddef{main}\endmoddef\nwstartdeflinemarkup\nwenddeflinemarkup
for i in range(100):
    i += 1
    \LA{}printing\RA{}

\nwendcode{}\nwbegindocs{2}\nwdocspar
And some more code:
\nwenddocs{}\nwbegincode{3}\moddef{printing}\endmoddef\nwstartdeflinemarkup\nwenddeflinemarkup
repr(i)

\nwendcode{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!